# Read URL in Java

Tags: java, url, exception, stream

My goal with this program is to extract a website's content and output it to console. However, an exception gets thrown every time I run this code. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, and if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thank you ahead of time!

```
public class twikiripper {


public static URL url;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        }catch(MalformedURLException ex){}
        try {
            url.openConnection();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }

            System.out.println(sb);



        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

My code is above. I was wondering, why am I always outputting Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException ? I seem to always throw this exception. I thought I was doing everything right.

What I am trying to do is display the output code from a website, that is all. Please help !

Comment: In your first try block a the local variable hides the field url. You've got two different variables with the same name. Change `URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");` to `url = new URL("http://www.google.com");` or follow NiVeRs answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary try-catch block in your code. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        url.openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        System.out.println(sb);



    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

And also make sure that your are importing the correct classes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for null pointer exception is:

In your code, in `url.openConnection();` variable url is local and its scope ends at the end of the its try block.

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class twikiripper {


    public static URL url;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try{
            url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); // I have changed this line
        }catch(MalformedURLException ex){}
        try {
            url.openConnection();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }

            System.out.println(sb);



        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i took url.openConnection(); line out completely, it was unneccesary

Answer (score 0):

In your first try block a the local variable hides the field url. You've got two different variables with the same name. Change URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); to url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); or follow NiVeRs answer. – Eritrean 8 mins ago

Correct! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
below code will fullfill your requirement --

package com.subham.testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test13 {

    public static URL url;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {


          url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            System.out.println("came exception");
        }

        try {
            url.openConnection();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }

            System.out.println(sb);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}



You were creating new url object  in first try block so in second try block was getting null as it was just decleared but not initialized.
```